# GitVersion source only from branch name

Tags: gitversion

By default GitVersion can increment version based on tags, branch names, commit messages, etc.

This is not convenient for my case because different people can increment version by mistake.

I'd like only branch name to be the source for GitVersion.

In GitVersion docs I've found only ignoring commit messages by adding "commit-message-incrementing: Disabled" line to GitVersion.yml

Any ideas how tags can be ignored?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you can. Tag is at the core of GitVersion. Check the "How it works" here:

https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more-info/how-it-works/